# Can I get crash report in fabric dashboard after install firebase crashlytics

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using firebase crashlytics in my app. and I want to see to crash report in fabric dashboard, but when I try to select my app to integrate to fabric it show 'Already Linked' message.
How can I integrate my app to show report on both.

Comment: Mike from Fabric and Firebase here. It's recommended to only have one crash reporter on iOS, not two so you would need to choose which reporter you want to use.